# Access individual button inside Qt's QDialogButtonBox

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

Long story short. I have one python module generated from ui file, let's say dialog.py this form contains QDialogButtonBox widget
`self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)`

The question is how can I access individual button inside this buttonBox?

I have tried using `ui.buttonBox.button(QDialogButtonBox.Ok).setEnabled(False)` but it did not work, the program crashed instead.
http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qdialogbuttonbox.html#button

The only thing I was able to come up is this:

```
ui.buttonBox.buttons()[0].setEnabled(False)
```

note plural button**s** and it works but I am not sure if this is portable and right way.

Here is original Qt link since this is pyqt5 
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/qdialogbuttonbox.html#button

Regards.

Comment: I have tried what you have tried and it works well for me. Could you show more code please

Comment: try with  `QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok`

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can say is that I am an idiot ;-)
I forgot to import QDialogButtonBox in this module and instead run python script directly using interpreter I ran it through 'sublime text' (text editor) build menu which gave me this message:

> [Finished in 3.1s with exit code -6]
>   So the answer is that there was no QDialogButtonBox symbol imported which I'd have known if I run it with python interpreter.