# Disabling custom button inside QDialogButtonBox

Tags: python, qt, pyside, pyside6, qt6

I have a QDialogButtonBox that contains the two custom buttons Start and Cancel. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31290792/how-to-change-the-caption-of-a-button-in-a-qdialogbuttonbox), the best way to add these buttons is as follows:

```py
button_box = QDialogButtonBox()
button_box.addButton("Launch", QDialogButtonBox.ButtonRole.AcceptRole)
button_box.addButton("Cancel", QDialogButtonBox.ButtonRole.RejectRole)
```

One of the two buttons must now be deactivated. I tried to adopt the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43440318/access-individual-button-inside-qts-qdialogbuttonbox):

```py
button_box.button(QDialogButtonBox.ButtonRole.AcceptRole).setDisabled(True)
```

but this seems only to work with the default qt buttons like Ok etc.
I came up with the following working solution, but I wanted to ask if there is a more direct way I missed.

```py
for btn in button_box.buttons():
    if btn.text() == "Launch":
        btn.setDisabled(True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to retrieve the button from the `addButton` function, and save it to a variable [according to the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/PySide6/QtWidgets/QDialogButtonBox.html#PySide6.QtWidgets.PySide6.QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.addButton).

```py
#create button box w/ custom buttons
button_box = QDialogButtonBox()
launch_button = button_box.addButton("Launch", QDialogButtonBox.ButtonRole.AcceptRole)
cancel_button = button_box.addButton("Cancel", QDialogButtonBox.ButtonRole.RejectRole)

# disable the launch button
launch_button.setDisabled(True)
```

Comment: Thanks. I got fooled by PyCharm. They only show the first overload which returns None

Comment: @sebwr IDE autocompletion is useful, but often results in becoming lazy: studying the documentation is **always** required.